# How to download a file using Angular and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, download

I am trying to download a file (the file can have various extensions, not just a specific one). From server I do receive the byte[] array, but in client the file comes corrupted.

I have tried to 
1. send from server a Resource file
2. send from server an InputStream file

This is the code from myBatis, the SQL

```
<resultMap id="downloadAttachmentMap" type="Document">
    <result column="id" property="id"/>
    <result column="fileName" property="fileName"/>
    <result column="docFile" property="docFile" javaType="_byte[]" jdbcType="BLOB" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ByteArrayTypeHandler"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="downloadDocumentById" resultMap="downloadAttachmentMap" parameterType="Long">
         SELECT td.id,
           TD.DOC_FILE_NAME      fileName,
           td.DOC_FILE            docFile
    FROM TAB_DOCUMENTS td
    WHERE td.id = #{docId}

</select>
```

Controller method which returns a Document object that has a field of type byte[].

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/download-document/{id}")
   public Document downloadEmpDocument(@PathVariable Long id) {
      Document doc =  employeeService.downloadDocument(id);
      return doc;
  }
```

This is the method from service in client-side:

```
 downloadEmpDocument(docId: number): Observable<Document>{
       return this
           .http
           .get<Document>(`${this.envConfig.baseUrl}/employee/download-document/${docId}`);
}
```

And lastly, here is the method from client that I am trying to download the file knowing its id.

```
downloadDocument(document: Document) {
    this.employeeService.downloadEmpDocument(document.id)
        .subscribe(doc => {
        const blob = new Blob([doc.docFile], {type:  "attachment; filename=\""+doc.filename+"\""});

         var link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         link.download = doc.fileName;
         link.click();
        });
}
```

I was expecting to download the file uncorrupted, but a corrupted file is downloaded.